# Linq Data Context - connect from web part as application pool identity

Tags: database, web-application, linq

I have an assembly with linq to sql mappings and I'd like to utilize it in my webpart. But when I try following:

```
DataList dataList = new DataList();
            dataList.DataSource = DB.Foo;
            dataList.DataBind();
```

in `CreateChildControls`, I'm getting sql exception that user IUSR could not log into database. I wonder why it tries to connect with IUSR while I have set another identity for my application pool and that user has access to database. How can I make it connect to database with application pool identity?

Comment: SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges runs code under application pool account.

Comment: @Alexander: I'd be happy to accept you comment as an answer to my question, so please post it as answer if don't mind.

Comment: it doesn't matter :)